# Connect Mac computer to PC local IP

Tags: networking, mac, desktop-computer

I have two computers, a PC and a Mac which are both on the same local network.

On the PC I'm running a local Apache server.

The PC's local IP is something like 192.168.1.2.

I can not load the local IP of the PC in a browser on my Mac to do web browser testing.

**How do I load pages from my PC's local server via the local IP on browsers running on my Mac?**

Other computers on the local network load pages via the IP just fine.

Comment: What server software are you using?

Comment: Have you checked any firewall settings and set up binding to listen to the other machines ip/your local subnet?

Comment: @Jonno Never did that though I have spent a modest amount of time with firewalls.

Comment: Can you access the web server from the machine hosting the web content by going to http://127.0.0.1?

Comment: Also, do you not see any response when you try to access content via http between machines?  Any 404, 500, or other errors?  What exactly happens when you try to browse?  Can these machines ping each other?

Comment: @Richie086 Yes, 127.0.0.1, the IP and localhost. Server isn't responding for the error message.

Comment: @John Could you try to disable the whole firewall in your Mac, to see if it works without it? [Here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642) are some instructions on how to do it, in case you don't know.